# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 FromRoute and FromBody Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I read Microsoft's documentation on [building web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but I don't see an example on how to merge route and body params, other than developing a custom model binder.  I believe I'm missing something because developing a custom model binder seems to be overkill for this common task.  How can I tell my application to create the model from route params and the body payload?

```
Request:
PUT /business/f8e5cf33-40b1-4b8e-8280-b1b60a459154
{"name": "MyBusiness", "street": "123 Main Street"}

Response:
400
{"Id": ["'Id' must not be empty."]}

// BusinessController
[Route("business/{id}")]
[ApiController]
public class BusinessController : Controller {
    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public ActionResult PutAsync(BusinessModel business) {
      ...
    }
}

// BusinessModel
class BusinessModel {
    // The `[FromRoute]` annotation has no affect
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate in two tags on the parameter section.

```
   // BusinessController
    [Route("business/{id}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BusinessController : Controller {
        [HttpPut]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public ActionResult PutAsync([FromBody]BusinessModel business, [FromRoute] int id) {
          ...
        }
    }
```

And after that asign that id to the model, if it is part of it.

Comment: I'm trying to leverage the "Automatic HTTP 400 Responses" functionality.  This functionality allows me to remove `if(!ModelState.IsValid)` checks in the action.  So the API is returning a 400 before the action runs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: Ok, now I get that if you take off the tags on the parameter section it should do that merge that you want, so it appears that it doesn't do it because your id is a Guid object, and it can't resolve that Guid construction only from the id.

Comment: I've tried with Guid, string, and ints without success.

Comment: What happens if you send some int on the Request with that same code with the id like Guid? In your request example the id is missing.

Comment: No matter the data type, I receive a message stating the Id is required.  In the Guid example above, `f8e5cf33-40b1-4b8e-8280-b1b60a459154` is the `id` param.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code which works is as follows (prams are case sensitive so one in route need match your property)

```
[Route("business/{Id}")]
[ApiController]
public class BusinessController : Controller {
    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public ActionResult PutAsync(BusinessModel business) {
      ...
    }
}

// BusinessModel
class BusinessModel {
    [FromRoute]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [FromForm]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [FromForm]
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```